# Excel - Equation to produce Sunday date based on week

Tags: excel, date, equation

I am working on a time sheet. There is a cell that requires a date based on the pay period. That date will always be Sunday date of that week. I am trying to create a formula that will look at today's date and report that Sunday. For an example last week, if I filled out my time sheet last Friday the 25th it would report Sunday the 27th. Does any one know how to create this equation with out populating extra data on a sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=TODAY()+(7-(WEEKDAY(TODAY())-1))
```

Comment: THANKS! Worked great.